# Connecting Two Rails Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a model called cities and a model called stores. I would like to connect my stores and cities model so that I will be able to call on the store's city if needed (e.g. @Store.city). How would I go about doing so?

I'm assuming that I need a has_many :cities tag in the store model and a belongs_to :store tag in the cities model. I get kind of lost past that point. Any help would be very much appreciated?

Comment: are there many stores in one city?

Comment: This is a question that's going to take a time investment from someone to answer. You'll probably have better luck getting someone to make that time investment if you accept answers to more of the questions you've asked in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First warning is that. Unless intended to, it is unconventional to use plural for model name in RoR. So your `Stores` should be `Store`. Similarly, for city.

I am guessing that you want to have a relationship where a city has_many stores. In this case, You would want a foreign key in your store signifying that the store belongs_to a city.

```
rails generate model City
rails generate model Store
```

in your Store model, you want to add

```
belongs_to :city
```

in your city model, you want to add

```
has_many :stores
```

**Update**

Make sure that in your your store table, you have a foregin key named `city_id`

**Answers**

"What do I do with the foreign key?"

You only have to add it to the table. Rails will automatically make this connection for you. To be more precise. In your `stores` table migration, make sure you have

```
.....
t.integer :city_id
.....
```

Comment: What do I do with the foreign key?

Comment: @TopChef..just make sure your `stores` table contains a column `city_id`, then Rails will understand by convention that it is the foreign key..otherwise you will have to explicitly mention the name of the foreign key in the relation like `has_many :stores, :foreign_key => "cityId"`

Answer (score 2):

**If each store is in only one city:**

First, make sure that your stores table has a `city_id` field.

your store model will contain a

```
belongs_to :city
```

and the city model will have

```
has_many :stores
```

This will allow you to access all the stores in a city:

```
@city = City.find_by_id(id)
@city.stores #gives an array of stores belonging to that city.
```

You can also get the city for a particular store:

```
@store = Store.find_by_id(id)
@store.city #gives the record for this store's city, this is based on the city_id field in your stores table
```

---

If your stores are chain stores, and have the potential of being in many cities, then you will need to set things up a little differently.  You will need another table between cities and stores for a "many to many" connection.  This table could be called `city_stores` where each record would contain one store_id and one city_id.

Then your models change a bit also:

```
model Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :city_stores
  has_many :cities, :through => :city_stores
end

model City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :city_stores
  has_many :stores, :through => city_stores
end

@store.cities #now gives a list of all the cities this store resides in
@city.stores #still gives a list of all stores in the city
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check this guide [A Guide to Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and yes once you have in your Store model:

`belongs_to :city`

and you have a:

`city_id` on your `stores` table, you will be able to do that and you also need to do the association on the other way:

in you City model:

`has_many :stores`

now you will be Able to do something like

```
store = Store.find(1)
store.city.name # => this will return the `name` field of the associated city
```

and you can do this too:

```
city = City.find(1)
city.stores # => this will return an array of the stores on the selected City
```

Comment: Should I make the foreign key an int? I am trying to migrate a column onto my existing table, but don't know what to specify it as. I currently have rails generate migration add_city_id_to_stores

Comment: Yes it should be `integer` for rails association through `id`

Comment: `add_column :stores,:city_id,:integer`

Comment: Then in you `new store` form you can add a select for the cities like: `<%= f.select :city_id, City.all.collect{ |c| [c.name, c.id ]}%>`